# CodeIgniter - Unique Value - Error Display

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a simple form, a newsletter subscription, which has two inputs: `email` and `city`. I use `is_unique` in form validation, but this error shows as text. I need to modify this text show in an alert box or warning.Need something to fix this error in design, suggestions please.

> user.php controller

```
<?php 

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function create_user() {
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $lang = $this->input->post("lang");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            if ($lang == "en") {
                if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                    $this->load->view('m_english_signup');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $this->load->view('d_english_signup');
                }
                } //if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
            else 
            {
                if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                    $this->load->view('m_arabic_signup');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $this->load->view('d_arabic_signup');
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            if ($query = $this->Users_model->create_member()) {
                if ($lang == "en") {
                    if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                        $this->load->view('m_english_thanks');
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->load->view('d_english_thanks');
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                        $this->load->view('m_arabic_thanks');
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->load->view('d_arabic_thanks');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You output the errors on your view. How are you handling the validation errors on your view?

Comment: nothing i add in view i only use this is_unique in controller and error show on view page i mention above. what i set in view please guide.

Comment: I think you should go with ajax call,to check whether email is already there or not

Comment: i use is_unique in form and it work fine but i need to show this error as alert / warning you can check link [link](http://fahad.myradio.pk)

Comment: Show your view page code where this error is displaying right now.

Comment: Okay, this can be done through javascript , store your error in a variable in your controller like $errors = validation_errors();, you can pull out email related error from $erros array and store it in a $email_error and in your view file write if(!empty($_POST) && $email_error!=''){?> <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('<?php echo $email_error;?>');
  });
</script> <?php }
you need to include jquery  in your view file for this

Comment: @user2936213 i already shared a live web link you can submit data and check i just mention the unique_id on table & colum [link](http://fahad.myradio.pk)

Answer (score 3):

I think Nilesh has the best solution that you need. By using javascript you can, if the email entered already exists, you can generate an alert. Alternatively you can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to style your `div`(assuming you have one above your email input):

```
<div class="alert" style="display: none"> 
    <a class="close" data-hide="alert" >×</a>  
    <Strong><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></strong>
</div>
<input name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
```

Then write some javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-hide]").on("submit", function(){
        $("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this solution can be preferred

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your own error message ?

try CodeIgnitor Userguide http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

Comment: `  $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique[users.email]','Email Address Is Already In Our Database Choose Another E-mail Id.'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');`
i already use but its not work!